# E0308 reading lines from file with for line in reader.lines()

Tags: io, rust

I am an experienced developer currently trying to teach myself Rust and am writing a simple program to read lines from a file. I have read the Rust std:io, std:result and other documentation forward and backwards and this code is largely taken straight from the docs.  I can't understand why the following program does not compile.

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    File::open("./data/test")
        .map_err(|err| err.to_string())
        .and_then( |mut dataFile| { 
             let mut reader = BufReader::new(dataFile);
             for line in reader.lines() {
                println!("{}",line.unwrap());

             };                           
        });        
}
```

The compile error I am receiving when I run `cargo build` is

```
src/main.rs:10:35: 16:10 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::result::Result<_, collections::string::String>`,
    found `()`
(expected enum `core::result::Result`,
    found ()) [E0308]
src/main.rs:10         .and_then( |mut dataFile| { 
src/main.rs:11              let mut reader = BufReader::new(dataFile);
src/main.rs:12              for line in reader.lines() {
src/main.rs:13                 println!("{}",line.unwrap());
src/main.rs:14    
src/main.rs:15              };                           
           ...
src/main.rs:10:35: 16:10 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I am running Rust 1.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mdup explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854788/155423), [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.map) and [`and_then`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) are used to *transform* a `Result` with a closure. `map` is used when you want to change the inner type, `and_then` is used when you want to chain a second thing that results in another `Result` without nesting them.

However, **neither** of these is idiomatic for your case as you are **not** transforming the value. Instead, you want a `match` or `if let` statement. These are more appropriate for *side effects*.

Additionally, Rust uses `snake_case` identifiers, and you don't need to have any of the variables be marked as mutable. These are all compiler warnings you would see once it compiles.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("./data/test")
        .map_err(|err| err.to_string());

    if let Ok(data_file) = f {
        let reader = BufReader::new(data_file);
        for line in reader.lines() {
            println!("{}", line.unwrap());
        };                           
    }        
}
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as though mdup's answer is helpful Shepmaster explains what the best way to do it is whihc is very helpful.

Comment: OK, just found out about the 5 min limit so apologies for the spelling above, can't corect it now. I was going to add I originally based this code on the examle in the documentation from Section 4.7 Error handling [https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#the-limits-of-combinators]. I  see now why they were using map as they are actually chaining the output in that example. I did have a first attempt that used matches but I had how they worked wrong in my head, this has really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using `and_then`, but `map`.

Correct code:

```
File::open("./data/test")
    .map_err(|err| err.to_string())
    .map(|mut dataFile| { 
         let mut reader = BufReader::new(dataFile);
         for line in reader.lines() {
            println!("{}",line.unwrap());
         };
    });
```

You can see it in both functions signatures:

```
fn and_then<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
fn map<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
```

The key difference here is that the operation `op` must return something wrapped in a `Result` in `and_then`'s case, whereas it doesn't have to be wrapped in `map`'s case. Your closure doesn't return anything, so in Rust's view it actually returns `()`, and `()` cannot match `Result<U, E>`. However `()` can match `U`, which is why the second signature works.